# Emberjs call view method from outside

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to be able to call a view method from outside of Ember but I can't figured it out yet.

Let's say I have this view :

```
App.ThisIsMyView = Ember.View.extend({
    myMethod: function( data ) {
        // Do something
    }
})
```

how can I call it from the outside ? Because I have tried to do this :

`App.ThisIsMyView.myMethod( data );`

But I really don't know.. I almost desperate to create an observer on my controller to trigger the view method, but that is pretty ugly.

Comment: In general, it is uncommon in Ember to explicitly call a view's methods from outside the view. If you can provide a jsbin illustrating what you're trying to accomplish, people could better help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
App.__container__.lookup("view:this_is_my_view").myMethod()
```

This App.**container** construct was create for debugging purposes and so this is not a suggested use.  That being said, if you absolutely must use it go ahead!